# return to old tab after closing the current tab using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser, tabs

How to close the current tab and return to old tab?
I am making the bill by using php + mysql + javascript.

This is my control flow from begin.

- When customers purchase items.the cashier open the add bill page in
  browser as the 1st tab.

  1. fill the form normally.(item's detail , customer's detail)
  2. click "old customer button" (to get customer's detail from previous purchase)
  3. the 2nd browser tab is open and display all customers in the database.
  4. select customer from the 2nd tab and store the customer's detail in html5 localstorage.
  5. close 2nd tab and return to the 1st tab.
  6. jquery load customer's  detail in localstorage to tab1's form.

i am currently at step 5. is there a way to tell the browser that 2nd tab is just child of 1st one.